# How to set jquery datepicker value to null using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to set the value of datepicker to null using jQuery.

I tried

```
$.datepicker._clearDate(this);
```

and

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().val('')
```

but not working. I'm using jQuery's datepicker plugin.

Comment: What are you tring to ask?

Comment: please write with description and code..

Comment: i need to set the value of datepicker to null using jquery  i even tried $.datepicker._clearDate(this); and $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().val('') but not working

Comment: What kind of plugin are you using? is it bootstrap?

Comment: using jquery's datepicker plugin

Comment: add the your full coding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try different belows:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('getDate');
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(2015,0,23)));
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign `null` to input field

```
$("#datepickerinputid").val('');
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. 
There is still date associated to the field, just not visually represented.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js` not the `jquery.datetimepicker.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this

1.Using input selector by name

```
$("input[name='your_date_picker_name']", this).val("");
```

2.If your date picker is associated with a form

```
$("input[name='your_date_picker_name']", $('#form_id')).val("");
```

3.Or simply try this

```
$( "#your_date_picker_name" ).datepicker('setDate','');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This looks to be for daterangepicker, not datepicker.