# On click of cancel button datepicker of jquery is stamping the date value

Tags: jquery, siebel

I have a cancel button on my datepicker in siebel open UI application and when I click on it, I want the datepicker to be hidden as well as no date to be stamped as when i select the date from datepicker and click on cancel  the respective date gets stamped which i dont want.

Here's my code:

```
1) $('.ui-datepicker').css("display", "none");
2) $('.ui-datepicker').datepicker('setDate',null);
```

where line 1 is for hiding the datepicker and line 2 for do nothing when clicking cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [How to set jquery datepicker value to null using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34761648/1587413)

especially this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','');
```