# How to set datepicker to load NULL by default when user has not set date?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

After setting up datepicker for Date of Birth. The default date/time loads with the format 2020-07-21 00:00:00 (yyyy-m-d H:i:s). This is if the user has not clicked on the field or not set date . See screenshot - https://prnt.sc/uvar2p

If the user has not set the date then it should be **null or empty** to show the user that they have to enter the date.

**Date of Birth field**

```
{!! Form::text('date_of_birth', null, array('class'=>'form-control datepicker', 'id'=>'date_of_birth', 'placeholder'=>__('Date of Birth'), 'autocomplete'=>'off')) !!}
```

So far I have tried the following and they haven't worked.

- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/set-datepicker-to-null

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker.("setDate", null);
```

- [How to set jquery datepicker value to null using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760310/how-to-set-jquery-datepicker-value-to-null-using-jquery/34760383)

```
$( ".datepicker").val('');
```

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('getDate');
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date(2015,0,23)));
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','');
```

None of the above works.

**What I want is by default if user has not set date of birth then it should be null.**

Comment: By default `DateTimePicker`s can't be set to null because `DateTime` can't be null, but you can set them to `DateTime.MinValue` which is the default value

Comment: `$( ".datepicker").val('');` within ready block?

Comment: You have to do this form validation. Like when user submit form date check is it today's date? If yes then alert him/her

Comment: Have you checked out the [datepicker API doc](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker)? [getDate()](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) should return null if no date is selected. You probably want to avoid checking the `val()` since the user could interact with the element you call `.datepicker()` on separate from actually interacting with the widget.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra tried that. Didn't work